# HTML table only echo one row instead of all in database into table

Tags: php, html, database, html-table, rows

I seem to be having an issue with my HTML formatting. I am calling the database to display all information within the table on a webpage. I have got the information coming down but I cannot seem to get all of the information to go into the table.

The formatting will only allow one row to be entered into the table and then the rest of the row go below in normal text format.

How would I go about getting all the information to sit in the table and automatically update when more information is added?

```
<?php
//connect to the server
$link = mysql_connect('*****', '*****', '****'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
}

mysql_select_db('******'); 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename");

        echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Region</td>
            <td>Cameraman</td>
            <td>Livestream?</td>
            <td>Event Title</td>
            <td>Lecturer</td>
            <td>Time</td>
            <td>Speaker</td>
            <td>ICE Contact</td>
            <td>Venue Address</td>
            <td>Venue Contact</td>
            <td>Additional Comments</td>
            <td>On App?</td>
            </tr>";

        WHILE($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):

            $date = $rows['date'];
            $region = $rows['region'];
            $cameraman = $rows['cameraman'];
            $livestream = $rows['livestream'];
            $eventtitle = $rows['eventitle'];
            $lecturer = $rows['lecturer'];
            $time = $rows['time'];
            $speaker = $rows['speaker'];
            $icecontact = $rows['icecontact'];
            $venuecontact = $rows['venueaddress'];
            $venuecontact = $rows['venuecontact'];
            $additionalcomments = $rows['additionalcomments'];
            $onapp = $rows['onapp'];



            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['date'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['region'] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $rows['cameraman'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['livestream'] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $rows['eventitle'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['lecturer'] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $rows['time'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['speaker'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['icecontact'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['venueaddress'] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $rows['venuecontact'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['additioncomments'] . "</td>";  
            echo "<td>" . $rows['onapp'] . "</td>";     
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";


        endwhile;
?>
```

http://cpdonline.tv/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.php

Comment: move the closing `table` tag to the outside of the loop. To get it to update automatically use javascript ( ajax most likely )

Comment: You are closing the `</table>` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made two boo boo's in your code:

1: You are not using these variables, delete them

```
        $date = $rows['date'];
        $region = $rows['region'];
        $cameraman = $rows['cameraman'];
        $livestream = $rows['livestream'];
        $eventtitle = $rows['eventitle'];
        $lecturer = $rows['lecturer'];
        $time = $rows['time'];
        $speaker = $rows['speaker'];
        $icecontact = $rows['icecontact'];
        $venuecontact = $rows['venueaddress'];
        $venuecontact = $rows['venuecontact'];
        $additionalcomments = $rows['additionalcomments'];
        $onapp = $rows['onapp'];
```

2: You are closing the table inside of the while loop

```
echo "</table>";


        endwhile;
```

Should be:

```
        endwhile;
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Brilliant! as you said that has allowed all the information to enter the table. Unfortunately there is now an additional row with no information in the table at the bottom. Any idea as to why?

Comment: Empty row in the database?

Comment: Unfortunately not, there is only 3 rows in the database. The table on the page is displaying 4 row.

Comment: If that is the only code you have, I cannot explain the empty row other then a empty row in the database

Comment: It is indeed the only code i have. 
Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: check the value isset and is not null inside while loop. if(isset($rows['date']) && $rows['date']!=''){ continue; } this will remove your blank row. put this code on starting of your while loop.